# Linked list delete node does not work

Tags: c#

Method finds the previous node of the next node that I want to delete. Then I try to connect the previous node with the next node of the node I want to delete however I the result I get is an linked list that has only the first element, while the others are deleted.

```
public void DeleteNode(Studentas stud )
{
    for (Mazgas d = head; d != null; d = d.Next)  
    { 
        if ( d.Next == null)  
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (d.Next.Duom.Name == stud.Name) 
        {
            Mazgas v = d;  
            v.Next = d.Next.Next;
            d.Next = null;
            break;
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not compile it but should work:

```
public void DeleteNode(Studentas stud )
{
    for (Mazgas d = head; d != null; d = d.Next)  
    { 
        if ( d.Next == null)  
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (d.Next.Duom.Name == stud.Name) 
        {
            d.Next  = d.Next.Next;
            break;
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't we need to make the deleted node to null ? Because it still exists however we cant reach it.

Comment: In C or C++ we had to. In C# is not mandatory. The Garbage Collector will pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: You want to delete an object in a linked list, based on a property of that object. Three cases:

1. Delete head of the list: Remainder is a valid Linked List.
2. Delete an element E in-between: connect predecessor to successor of element E. Manfred Radlwimmer's answer should work in that case.
3. Delete last element E: predecessor.Next of E should become null.

If you access your linked list by the head, removing the head will remove the entire list. In that case you should make the head's successor the new head.